# a program that asks for a users age and tells the user when he/she will turn 100

Tags: python

Create a program that asks the user to enter their name and their age. Print out a message addressed to them that tells them the year that they will turn 100 years old.

here is my code which doesn't work:

```
username=input("Please enter your name")
userage=input("Please enter your age")

def age100(userage):

   turn=100-userage+2017

   return turn


age100(userage)

message= 'Hello %s, your age is %d and you will turn 100 in the year %d' %(username,userage, turn)
print(message)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call the function, but you never save or use the result. This should fix it:

```
username=input("Please enter your name")
userage=input("Please enter your age")

def age100(userage):

   turn=100-userage+2017

   return turn


turn = age100(userage)

message= 'Hello %s, your age is %d and you will turn 100 in the year %d' %(username,userage, turn)
print(message)
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me why I am getting this error? Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/rr.py", line 11, in <module>
    turn = age100(userage)
  File "C:/Python34/rr.py", line 6, in age100
    turn=100-userage+2017
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Because userage is a string, but you're trying to do math with it. Convert it to int: ```int(userage)```. You should also try reading through a basic Python tutorial. To get your question reopened, edit your original error message or incorrect output into the question.

Comment: username=input("Please enter your name")
userage=input("Please enter your age")

def age100(userage):
    turn=100-int(userage)+2017
    return turn

turn = age100(userage)

message= 'Hello %s, your age is %d and you will turn 100 in the year %d' %(username,int(userage), turn)
print(message)
 thanks! this code works now